# How to replace componentwillunmount at Mobx in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have "sign up" and "sign in" router.
I can move to "sign in" router from "sign up" router with Button.
So when I put some information at "sign in" and move to "sign up" 
and come back to "sign in", the input data is left at store.
So I made "`componentwillunmount`" to initialize store data when unmount. 
But is there the other way using mobx like `autorun` or `reaction`? not using "`componentwillUnmount`"
Could you give me the concepts or example of the other persons?

Thank you so much.

Comment: why would you avoid using `componentWillUnmount` ?

Answer (score 0):

First, please check the word that it's 'componentWillUnmount', not 'componentwillUnmount'.

Second, I think that you do not have to replace the 'componentWillUnmount' function. You can use the same store on two pages with 'inject'.